# Complexity class for some group and graph homomorphism problems

Tags: graph-isomorphism, gr.group-theory

Given two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ what is the complexity class in which the following problem belongs?

$$\mathsf{Is }|Hom(G_1,G_2)|>0$$

Given two graphs $H_1$ and $H_2$ what is the complexity class in which the following problem belongs (Answered by Ricky Demer in comment)?

$$\mathsf{Is }|Hom(H_1,H_2)|>0$$

Comment: The latter [is "NP-complete"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism#Connection_to_coloring_and_girth), even when $H_2$ is a triangle. $\;$

Comment: The first one has a quasi-poly time algorithm, by my answer here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/33096/129 (the same technique applies).

Comment: From your recent series of questions I get the impression that you are learning about a subject, but maybe should be reading more and/or thinking more about answering your own questions before asking them here, since the answers are either not hard to figure out or not hard to find via Google or Wikipedia...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As I mentioned in a comment,) The graph problem [is NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism#Connection_to_coloring_and_girth), even when H<sub>2</sub> is a triangle.

By putting 3 isolated vertices into H<sub>1</sub>, one gets a modified instance such that if the

original instance had no graph homomorphisms then the modified instance also has no

graph homomorphisms else the modified instance has more than 6 graph homomorphisms.

Taking the group problem literally, it is in [DTIME](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dtime)(1), since it's decided by the algorithm ACCEPT.

On the other hand, let ∃NZH be the result of instead interpreting the "0" from the

group problem as "the cardinality of the singleton whose element is [the zero morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_morphism#Examples)".

By [Reingold's result](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/148550/sl.pdf), ∃NZH is in ​ [GC](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:G#gc)$\hspace{-0.02 in}\big(\hspace{-0.04 in}\lceil \hspace{-0.02 in}$log<sub>2</sub>(|G<sub>1</sub>|)$\hspace{-0.02 in}\rceil \hspace{-0.06 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.06 in}\lceil \hspace{-0.02 in}$log<sub>2</sub>(|G<sub>2</sub>|)$\hspace{-0.02 in}\rceil$,[logspace](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:L#l)$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)$ , ​ since that class

[gives the verifier two-way read access](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0097539793258295#page=4) to the alleged proof. ​ Furthermore (still using Reingold), logspace machines can compute such non-zero homomorphisms given 2-way read access to

such witnesses. ​ Additionally, by [this answer's bound on the number of non-isomorphic groups](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/33096/6973)

(which I don't know how to prove), the *negation* of ∃NZH is in

GC$\hspace{-0.02 in}\big(\hspace{-0.03 in}\big[\hspace{-0.04 in}\lceil$log<sub>2</sub>(|G<sub>1</sub>|)$\hspace{-0.03 in}\rceil^{\hspace{-0.02 in}2}\hspace{-0.05 in}+\hspace{-0.06 in}\lceil$log<sub>2</sub>(|G<sub>2</sub>|)$\hspace{-0.03 in}\rceil^{\hspace{-0.02 in}2}$ ordinary bits$\hspace{-0.02 in}\big]\hspace{-0.03 in}$+[1 pointer to the [advice string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_%28complexity%29)]

,logspace$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)\hspace{-0.04 in}\big/\hspace{-0.04 in}n^{O\left(\hspace{-0.02 in}(\hspace{.02 in}\log(n))^{\hspace{.02 in}2}\hspace{-0.02 in}\right)}$.

(The pointer is to where the advice string gives [an ordered pair of reference groups with no non-zero homomorphisms] such that each input group is isomorphic to the corresponding reference group.)

I'm not aware of any evidence for there being $\big[\hspace{-0.02 in}$a set S of ordered pairs $\langle \hspace{-0.02 in}$m,n$\hspace{-0.02 in}\rangle$

with min(m,n) not bounded above$\hspace{-0.02 in}\big]$ such that the *complement* of the language

$\: \big\{\hspace{-0.05 in}\langle \hspace{-0.02 in}$m,n,G<sub>1</sub>,G<sub>2</sub>$\rangle$ ​ : ​ $\langle \hspace{-0.02 in}$m,n$\hspace{-0.02 in}\rangle \hspace{-0.03 in}\in$ S ​ and ​ and ​ |G<sub>1</sub>| < m ​ and ​ |G<sub>2</sub>| < n

 ​ ​ ​ ​ and ​ G<sub>1</sub> and G<sub>2</sub> are both [2-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group) ​ and ​ $\langle \hspace{-0.02 in}$G<sub>1</sub>,G<sub>2</sub>$\rangle \hspace{-0.03 in}\in$ ∃NZH $\hspace{-0.08 in}\big\}$

is in ​ GC$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big(\hspace{-0.03 in}o\hspace{-0.02 in}\big(\hspace{-0.03 in}$(log(m+n))<sup>3</sup>$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)\hspace{-0.02 in}$,[DTIME](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dtime)$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big(\hspace{-0.03 in}$2<sup>o(log(m)$\cdot$log(n))</sup>$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)\hspace{-0.04 in}\big)\hspace{-0.04 in}\big/\hspace{-0.04 in}$[2^$\big(\hspace{-0.04 in}$(m+n)<sup>o(1)</sup>$\hspace{-0.02 in}\big)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_%28complexity%29)

or in ​ [NTIME](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#ntime)$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big(\hspace{-0.03 in}$2<sup>o(log(m)$\cdot$log(n))</sup>$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)\hspace{-0.04 in}\big/\hspace{-0.04 in}n^{o\hspace{-0.02 in}\left(\hspace{-0.02 in}(\hspace{.02 in}\log(m+n))^{\hspace{.02 in}2}\hspace{-0.02 in}\right)}$ ,

where all five [little-o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)s are as min(m,n) increases without bound.

However, I certainly suspect that the negation of ∃NZH is already in those two classes,

i.e., without needing to bring S into the picture or assume that the groups are 2-groups.

Comment: I dont understand implication of http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/148550/sl.pdf to Graph Iso problem?

Comment: So deciding if number of graph or group homo is $>0$ is in $P$ while deciding $=0$ is in quasi poly?

Comment: No, for graphs that's NP-hard, and for groups it's extremely easy $\hspace{2.38 in}$ (since there's always the zero homomorphism). $\:$

Comment: (Hopefully my edit made this clear, but: ​ I'm not claiming that Reingold's result is relevant to Graph Isomorphism.) ​ ​ ​ ​